# Silverlight Accordion tool Margin Issue

Tags: c#, silverlight, accordion, silverlight-5.0

My issue related to design, I use Silverlight Accordion tool and I put Datagrid inside it, but I have an issue with the margin :

[image]

How can I remove this space (yellow part) ?

This is my code:

```
<toolkit:Accordion Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,200,0,0" BorderBrush="#FFE4E4E4">
        <toolkit:AccordionItem Header="Statment of facts">
            <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="129" x:Name="dgSOF" Width="1021"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ocSOFs, ElementName=myRoot}" RowHeight="30" BorderBrush="#FFE4E4E4">
                <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn/>
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn/>
                </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            </sdk:DataGrid>
        </toolkit:AccordionItem>
</toolkit:Accordion>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Padding property of the accordion item to zero

Comment: I have pasted your code into a new Silverlight project and it does not have this margin there by default. Have you got an implicit styles that might be setting a padding on any of the controls?